# PHPMYADMIN: Access field in EXISTS clause

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am sure it's just a typo, but how to write the following query correctly in PHPMyAdmin?

```
SELECT DISTINCT `email_address` as tmp1 
FROM `already_customer_checks` 
WHERE `is_customer` = 0 
AND NOT EXISTS (
                    SELECT * 
                    FROM `already_customer_checks` 
                    WHERE `email_address` = tmp1 
                    AND `is_customer` = 1
                )
```

> Error: #1054 - Unknown table field 'tmp1' in where clause

Background: I want to get all e-mail addresses which exist with 'is_customer' = 0 and do not have another existance in the table with 'is_customer' = 1.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: What is tmp1? If it has to be a string, you probably have to add it lin `'tmp1'`..

Comment: `tmp1` is not visible/available in the sub select

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT `email_address` as 'tmp1' FROM `already_customer_checks` WHERE `is_customer` = 0 AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM `already_customer_checks` WHERE `email_address` = 'tmp1' AND `is_customer` = 1)

This works, but the result is wrong. The result includes fields where `is_customer` = 1 as well.

Comment: @RiggsFolly So, I need to use two queries and a foreach for it? There is no way to solve it with one query?

Comment: Sub queries are already their own queries.

Comment: You can self-join to determine whether there exists (or doesn't) a matching record where is_customer = 1: `SELECT DISTINCT t1.email_address as tmp1 FROM already_customer_checks AS t1 LEFT JOIN already_customer_checks AS t2 ON ( t1.email_address = t2.email_address AND t2.is_customer = 1 ) WHERE t1.is_customer = 0 AND t2.email_address IS NULL`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do it with a subquery you need to put the alias `tmp1` on the table, not on the column. And then:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT `email_address`
FROM `already_customer_checks` as tmp1 
WHERE `is_customer` = 0 
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * 
    FROM `already_customer_checks` 
    WHERE `email_address` = tmp1.`email_address`
    AND `is_customer` = 1
)
```

You might also consider the comment proposed by @kmoser, which *could* be more efficient, if less clear. According to the MySQL docs:

> A LEFT [OUTER] JOIN can be faster than an equivalent subquery because the server might be able to optimize it better—a fact that is not specific to MySQL Server alone.

But if you use that SQL proposed by @kmoser, you probably don't want to alias the `email_address` column with `tmp1`.